# FreeBSD DHCP server on multiple interfaces

Tags: freebsd, dhcp-server

I have FreeBSD server (7.2) which has a lot of interfaces (vlans, count near 100). I want to configure DHCP server with separate pools for each interface. What program should I use? Thanks for any advices or config examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by reading http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/network-dhcp.html#NETWORK-DHCP-SERVER you can find out, that you:

- can use [isc-dhcp31-server](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/url.cgi?ports/net/isc-dhcp31-server/pkg-descr)
- can configure pools for each subnet you want

```
subnet 192.168.24.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 { ... }
subnet 192.168.23.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 { ... }
```

- you can make isc-dhcp listen on the devices you want (/etc/rc.conf):

```
dhcpd_ifaces="dc0"
dhcpd_ifaces="vr0"
```

another option is to use [dnsmasq](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/url.cgi?ports/net/dnsmasq/pkg-descr), comes with a dns-cacher included.

Comment: Trying to configure using your advice. results will be later ...

Comment: Yes, It works. But I'm trying to write my own dhcp server on python for better config handling via database backend.

Comment: http://skalyanasundaram.wordpress.com/dhcp/dhcp-with-ldap-support/